# Laravel - L5Modular Organizing modules by folder causes routing errors

Tags: php, laravel, module

Good day, I have recently pursued programming using laravel and found L5Modular fitting my needs until i encountered one problem. I receive a

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

error upon creating this kind of folder setup.

```
laravel-project/
    app/
    |-- Modules/
        |-- backend/
            |-- ModuleOne/
                |-- Controllers/
                   |-- FoobarController.php
                |-- Models/
                   |-- Foobar.php
                |-- Views/
                   |-- index.blade.php
                |-- Translations/
                   |-- en/
                      |-- example.php
                      |-- routes.php
                      |-- helper.php
        |-- frontend/
            |-- ModuleTwo/
                |-- Controllers/
                   |-- FoobarController.php
                |-- Models/
                   |-- Foobar.php
                |-- Views/
                   |-- index.blade.php
                |-- Translations/
                   |-- en/
                      |-- example.php
                      |-- routes.php
                      |-- helper.php
```

the reason I like this kind of structure is because I used to code CI. Is there any way I can get around this without relying on the `route.php`? Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't add a config file, this package loads the modules by looking into the first level of the `Modules` folder. In your case there are `frontend` and `backend`. Then the service provider looks for needed files within these "supposed" modules (FA routes.php). But in your case there are no such files.

[source](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular/blob/master/src/ModuleServiceProvider.php)

What you could do, is to add a `modules.php` into your projects `app/config` folder, which should contain something like this:

```
return [
    'enable' => array(
        'backend/ModuleOne',
        'frontend/ModuleTwo',
    ),
];
```